# How to implement onItemClickListener in List Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

following is my ListActivity, onCreate code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            fakeTripBuilder();

            setContentView(R.layout.cutom_list_view);

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.custom_row_view, 
                    new String[] {"stop","distance","time","icon","mode"},
                    new int[] {R.id.text_stop,R.id.text_distance, R.id.text_time, R.id.icon, R.id.text_mode});

            populateList();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

inside the the same class i have the following method

```
 @Override
       protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
           super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
           Log.d("Travel","You choosed!");
           Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
           Toast.makeText(this, "You Choosed"+o.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

and here is the "custom_list_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000fff"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFff00"
    android:text="No data"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is, onListItemClick method do not call when i click on it. Help !!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the NullPointerException?

Comment: why are u setting a single layout and setting it in setContentView and listview

Comment: you are getting the null pointer because you are not setting the list view layout in findViewByID of listView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a reference to the ListView in a ListActivity you should call:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

You do not need to set a click listener, it already has one. Simply override:

```
 @Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Object item = lv.getAdapter().getItem(position);

 }
```

And in your xml file, the ListView should have the id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

**Edit**

You need to remove

```
android:clickable="false"
```

from the layout to allow any child views to be clicked

Comment: in XML its defined as :  android:id="@id/android:list", And in the same class i have implemented the "onListItemClick", but it do not invoke. Thats why I tried to do as its in the question.

Comment: not android:id="@id/android:list, but android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: Yes, it has to be exactly "@android:id/list" or it will not work.

Comment: now there are no errors. But "onListItemClick" do not get called.

Comment: Edited above, you need to remove android:clickable="false"

Comment: it make sense to remove it. I didnt see it. But still its not working. :(

Comment: there was a problem in XML. I set all elements in XML to  android:focusable="false", then the touch method started to work.

Answer (score 1):

**A lot has changed since this question was asked in 2012. This is an update to the accepted answer**

To use `onItemClickListener` in your `ListActivity`, just override the `onListItemClick(...)` method like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    ListView myListView = getListView();
    Object itemClicked = myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Clicked: " + item + " \nPosition: " + id,

    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Notice the `getItem()` method instead of `getItemAtPosition()` in the accepted  answer**

**Remember:** for this to work, you need to have a listview with id `list`, else your app will crash.

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    />
```

Comment: You still need to put android:id="@android:id/list" as id of the ListView not just list

Answer (score 0):

> ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.layout.cutom_list_view);

You should use R.id.listview_id instead, that should be defined in R.layout.cutom_list_view

like so:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/listview_id"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

EDIT:

R.layout.cutom_list_view is id of your layout file, but you should find listview by its own id, defined like android:id="@+id/listview_id", so the id will be R.id.listview_id

Comment: what do you mean by layout xml? and what should I put there ?

Comment: in this layout: cutom_list_view

Comment: sorry, this is for Activity, not for ListActivity, look at @David Scott answer

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the onListItemClick method if you want to catch click events on your list.