# onListItemClick doesn't work

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, onclicklistener, listitem

So, my `onListItemClick` is not working for some reason. I use the same code structure in another activity and that one is working perfectly. And when I try to implement the same method here, it just doesn't work at all. The `Toast` doesn't work. And the intent to detailactivity also doesn't work. I'm sure my naming and labeling is fine. The list items doesn't even feel like they are clickable. Can someone help me out here, please?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String objectId;
    protected List<ParseObject> mInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    //**** There is a bunch of code here that takes import the list view from an adapter. I believe they are working fine. ***//
    }

    //**** this part below is not working. This is the section where if you click on the list item, it brings you to the detailactivity.
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id){
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ParseObject infoObject = mInfo.get(position);
        String objectId = infoObject.getObjectId();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),objectId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent Details = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        Details.putExtra("objectId", objectId);
        startActivity(Details);
    }
```

Comment: did you set the listener to the listView ? like `listview.setOnItemClickListener` ?

Comment: Hi, kindly show the logcat warnings and errors

Comment: No. Where do I do that? and how to do that? Why do I need that? I use this code in another activity without setOnItemClickListener and it works fine.

Comment: there is no logcat and warning. it feels like the whole onListItemClick doesn't exist. So when I pressed on a list item nothing happened.

Comment: kindly check my answer ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to solve this by adding `android:focusable="false"` inside of the the views in the listview/customlayout that will be imported to the activity. I got the answer from this link:
[onListItemClick is not working for listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765120/onlistitemclick-is-not-working-for-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Please implement the onListItemClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

//code code code
```

}

Then when you set the onItemCLick use

```
setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Why do I need this? I don't use this on my other activity and that one works fine. When I put this on, it is red.

Comment: did you import the class... its because you are overriding a method which comes from the onItemClickListener class

Comment: yes. and it turns to adapterview.onitemclicklistener. and error message "class MainActivity must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onitemclick(adapterview..)' in 'onitemclicklistener'". Where do I put setOnItemClickListener(this)?

Comment: Oh I have just read something else... maybe it will help.. 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299426/how-to-implement-onitemclicklistener-in-list-activity

Comment: what is the name of your list?

Comment: name or id? id is android:id/list

Comment: kindly check the link did it help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83097/discussion-between-sheychan-and-stanley-santoso).

Answer (score 1):

İf you use a custom adapter to fill listview and involve clickable components such as Button, İmageView. onListItemClick will don't work because it won't be able to decide which component will be listened. solution is "android:focusable:"false"" keyword. thanks to this, Listener will only focus items which are populated custom adapter by you.

Like this:

```
<Button
android:focusable="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="4dp"
android:background="colorCode"
/>
```

I have used this button to seperate each list view items. But it caused your problem. I think if you will list items, You shouldnt use clicable components in 
template xml.

Happy Coding..
Vd.